# Accessing the last argument passed in a bash function, then shifting it

Tags: bash

I have a simple function in bash which I want to take any number of arguments.  What I'd like to do is echo the last argument passed to the function, and then shift, and repeat until I am out of arguments.

Here is my code:

```
test(){
    while [ $# -ne 0 ]
    do
        echo "${@: -1}"
        shift  
    done
}
```

However, the shift doesn't seem to take place.

If I run:

```
test a b c d
```

it will return

```
d
d
d
d
```

Whereas I obviously would like to return

```
d
c
b
a
```

What am I doing wrong?  Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`shift` doesn't remove the last argument, it removes the first one. `$2` becomes `$1`, `$3` becomes `$2`, etc. `d` will always be the last argument because items are being popped off the front.

If you want to print all the arguments in reverse order, I'd suggest:

```
for ((i = $#; i > 0; --i)); do
    echo "${!i}"
done
```

Alternatively, you could mimic shifting from the right side with:

```
while (($# > 0)); do
    echo "${@: -1}"
    set -- "${@:1:$#-1}"
done
```

Also, another way to write `${@: -1}` is `${!#}`. That might be too clever, though. That kind of trickery is something you'd see in some inscrutable Perl script.

Comment: omg thanks.  I obviously didn't quite understand how shift works.

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
revargs() {
    local sgra=()
    for arg; do sgra=("$arg" "${sgra[@]}"); done
    printf "%s\n" "${sgra[@]}"
}
revargs foo bar baz qux
```

```
qux
baz
bar
foo
```

This just occurred to me: it's pretty cheesy, but it's short.

```
revargs() {
    printf "%s\n" "$@" | tac
}
```